# Bitcoin Client - How do I find the destination address of an incoming transaction?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, address

I'm mining Bitcoins and have multiple incoming addresses in my bitcoin-qt wallet.

When I get a payout for mining in the "Transactions" tab it shows the amount of BTC I received and the type is set to "Mined".

Now I see a lot of transactions, but I have no clue for which incoming wallet address these payments were originally made for.

How can I figure out the destination address in the wallet for incoming transactions? And if I can't; why?

Comment: Settings > Options > Display > Display addresses in transaction list

Comment: Nick, that's an answer not a comment.  Please post it below so this question can get marked with the proper answer.

Comment: @NickODell - Thanks, but that still doesn't show the incoming address for mined transactions. It does show the address for normal payments: http://i.imgur.com/QphomGx.png

Comment: @Casper I don't understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to find the addresses of transactions inside blocks you mine? Are you trying to find the input addresses of coinbase (mining reward) transactions?

Comment: @NickODell - I'm mining with p2pool. When I connect to the p2pool network with my p2pool client I have to provide a payment address for mined blocks. My miner then connects to the p2pool client and starts mining. The pool then pays me to the address I provided for the blocks I mine. And I was wondering how come the incoming payments do not show this address I gave earlier. It's just n/a (and somehow the wallet knows those payments come from mined blocks, because the type is "Mined").

Comment: @Casper Ah, ok. I was confused by how many there were. It's not giving an input address, because p2pool pays you directly from the coinbase. Remember, coinbase transactions don't have a source address - their security is guaranteed entirely by how hard it is to change the block.

Comment: @NickODell "*..payments don't have a source address..*". But each payment must have a destination, right? And the destination is the address I gave p2pool? And that's what should show up in the transaction list? Sorry, I'm still a bit confused..there's probably something basic I'm missing here on how mining works.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help. Do a getrawtransaction  1

For example, `getrawtransaction e12766de3b8b9532c0cca09a146c8a87e176ef39ec3823f1ea263401c77c465e 1` is this

```
"result":[{
        "hex":"01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff2a0313ad051d4d696e656420627920416e74506f6f6c20626a38186bcefb2055e11be1d60c000000153904ffffffff015af73695000000001976a9149524440a5b54cca9c46ef277c34739e9b521856d88ac00000000",
        "txid":"e12766de3b8b9532c0cca09a146c8a87e176ef39ec3823f1ea263401c77c465e",
        "version":1,
        "locktime":0,
        "vin":[{
            "coinbase":"0313ad051d4d696e656420627920416e74506f6f6c20626a38186bcefb2055e11be1d60c000000153904",
            "sequence":4294967295
        }],
        "vout":[{
            "value":25.0340745,
            "n":0,
            "scriptPubKey":{
                "asm":"OP_DUP OP_HASH160 9524440a5b54cca9c46ef277c34739e9b521856d OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
                "hex":"76a9149524440a5b54cca9c46ef277c34739e9b521856d88ac",
                "reqSigs":1,
                "type":"pubkeyhash",
                "addresses":["1Ebb8NfVmKMoGuMJCAEbVMv2dX8GnzgxSa"]
            }
        }],
        "blockhash":"00000000000000000f312f367314d9c9880ac990d3e759092407a088a104cadd",
        "confirmations":1,
        "time":1440816100,
        "blocktime":1440816100
    }]
```

As you can see, it's a coinbase transaction, with a vout of the address it's paid to. The Bitcoin-Qt interface may not show it (because it doesn't really matter), but if you run that command on your mining tx you will see where it went :)

Answer (score 1):

In Bitcoin Core v0.15.1 you go to the transaction tab in bitcoin-qt and double-click on a transaction. It shows you the transaction details including the To: address.

Answer (score 0):

getrawtransaction (txid) => gives you raw transaction X
take that and calc 
decoderawtransaction (X) , after that look at "vout" and find the address the transaction send the bitcoin to .
All in Bitcoin-qt console